# How to save element.text in document.xml

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I did a search and replace function in .docx document. I use module python-docx:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from docx import *

document = opendocx('test.docx')

TAG_LIST=[u'TAG1',u'TAG2',u'TAG3']
VALUE_LIST=[u'TEST1',u'TEST2',u'TEST3']

def search(document):
    result = False
    for element in document.iter():
        if element.text == '{':
            result=True
        if result and element.text != '}':
            for i in range(0,len(TAG_LIST)):
                if element.text == TAG_LIST[i]:
                     element.text=re.sub(TAG_LIST[i], VALUE_LIST[i], element.text)
                     print(element.text)

search(document)
```

This function finds the document tags in `{}`, verifies them with a `TAG_LIST` and makes replace to `VALUE_LIST`. I want to save `element.text` after `re.sub` function but don't know how to do it. I know that it is possible to read the entire text of `document.xml`, then do a replace, but loading the text into a buffer spends a lot of memory. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: is the document really that big?  It seems to me that `opendocx` *probably* has already read in the whole thing...

Comment: @mgilson. Yes, you're right .... unfortunately I did not find other ways to replace the text. in that case, just a question: how can I save the result back to the file?

Comment: No idea :).  I've never used docx before.  It looks like there is a [`savedocx`](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/d6d837243f275abc2eab99d9602ce28d20e42069/docx.py#L973) function, but that's as far as I got ;-)